# Mailjet Unsubscribe statistics

Tags: php, mailjet

Am trying to get mailjet statistics using this code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \Mailjet\Resources;
$mj = new \Mailjet\Client('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$body = [
'EventType' => "unsub",
'Url' => "http://example.com/Eventcallbackurl"];
$response = $mj->post(Resources::$Eventcallbackurl, ['body' => $body]);
$response->success();
var_dump($response->getData()));
```

so that's code returns the following error:

MJ18 A EventCallbackURL resource with value "5|false" for EventType|Backup already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i may not understand your question as well, but may this help :

```
$filters = array('CustomID' => 'the custom id when creating a capmaign');
$response = $mj->get(Resources::$Messagesentstatistics, array('filters' => $filters))
```

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Like the API answered, you already registered that resource. If you want to modify the url, you might want to use a `PUT`, with the `ID` `unsub|false` and the payload `[ "Url" => $newURL ]`

Comment: what do you mean by ID,i changed the post to put but it returns ==> array (size=3)
  'ErrorInfo' => string '' (length=0)
  'ErrorMessage' => string 'Object not found' (length=16)
  'StatusCode' => int 404

Comment: try that: ```$body = [
  'Url' => "my new url"
];

$response = $mj->put(Resources::$Eventcallbackurl, ['id' => '5|unsub', 'body' => $body]);```

Comment: its return the following array=============>>>

[0] => Array
                        (
                            [APIKeyID] => 194657
                            [EventType] => unsub
                            [ID] => 20250
                            [IsBackup] => 
                            [Status] => alive
                            [Url] => http://example.com/mailjet/
                            [Version] => 1
                        )

Comment: so,that's mean that the information must be in my website callbackurl?

Comment: i just need a list of emails which has been unsubscribed :'(

Comment: Have a look at the [listrecipient](http://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/listrecipient/) resource, it contains this information. Hope it helps

Comment: @arnaud.breton it's returning the count not the emails,thnx anyway :(

Comment: If you look into the "Data" collection, you'll have the ContactID and its subscription status in a given ListID. Is it what you're looking for?